# Why does it work when inject "org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder" to "DaoAuthenticationProvider"?

Tags: spring, spring-security

In `"DaoAuthenticationProvider"`, the `"passwordEncoder"` field is an instance of `"org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder"`
. But why it works when an instance of "org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder" is injected to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder takes an Object parameter type.

In the code, it runs instanceof to check for org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder and wraps the parameter in a proxy implementation of org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder.

[source is here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java)